# What's the most efficient way to filter QuerySet to feed datatables?

Tags: python, django, datatables

In order to filter out a `QuerySet` using [`django_datatables_view`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-datatables-view) to feed [`datatables`](http://datatables.net/), I'm trying to override the method `get_initial_queryset`, but cannot `itertools.chain` or come up with a clear `Q` object expressions to do the job.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    identity = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Status(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student')
    status = models.TextField()
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

So to get the latest `Status` of each and every `Student` and actually merge/combine them into a single `QuerySet` object to make it work in `django_datatables_view`, what should I do?

Comment: You’ve got two `time = models.DateTimeField()` in your `Status` models

Comment: Sorry, just corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood is that you need to override these two functions:

```
def get_initial_queryset(self):
    return Status.objects.select_related('student')

def prepare_results(self, qs):
    json_data = []
    for item in qs:
        json_data.append([item.student, item.status])
    return json_data
```

For more details [read the docs here.](https://bitbucket.org/pigletto/django-datatables-view)

Comment: It's not this simple. Well, if `QuerySet` instance is not returned in `get_initial_queryset` function, you basically have to override lots of other functions including `get_context_data`, `ordering`, `paging`, `prepare_results`, and it's a pain in the ass, so I'm looking for a way to combine those `QuerySet` into a single `QuerySet`

Comment: Sorry my bad. Changed the get_initial_queryset function to return queryset. You are right, probably you need to override some more functions as per your detailed requirement. What do you mean from combine those queryset ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if this is the most efficient, but you can do this(this is untested):

```
students = Student.objects.all()
status_ids = []

for student in students:
    latest_status_id = Status.objects.filter(student=student) \
                                     .latest('time').id
    status_ids.append(latest_status_id)

latest_statuses = Status.objects.filter(pk__in=statues)
```